# what is the proper way to create a Date-Time axis for the dc.js bubble chart?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Struggling my way through dc.js bubble charts.

My objective is to have the X axis be a date/time line.
I have the following code, which works fine with a linear X, but shows nothing with the date/time:

http://jsfiddle.net/eugene_goldberg/LL41xxho/13/

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="bubble-chart" class="dc-chart">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

var data = [
        {date: "12/27/2012", label: "a1", x: 2, y: 190, bubble: 5},
        {date: "12/28/2012", label: "a2", x: 2, y: 10,  bubble: 5},
        {date: "12/29/2012", label: "a3", x: 95, y: 300, bubble: 10},
        {date: "01/04/2013", label: "a9", x: 51, y: 90,  bubble: 1},
        ];

var ndx = crossfilter(data);

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse;
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
});

var dateDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.date;});
var xDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.x;});

var dateGroup = dateDim.group().reduce(
    function(p, v) {
        ++p.count;
        p.label = v.label;
        p.bubble = v.bubble;
        p.x = v.x;
        p.y = v.y;

        return p;
    },
    function(p, v) {
        --p.count;
        p.bubble = 0;
        p.label = "";
        p.x = 0;
        p.y = 0;

        return p;
    }, function() {
        return { count: 0, x: 0, y:0, label: "" };
    });

var minDate = dateDim.bottom(1)[0].date;
var maxDate = dateDim.top(1)[0].date;
var xRange = [-10, d3.max(dateGroup.all(), function(d) { return d.value.x + d.value.bubble*2; }) ],
    yRange = [-10, d3.max(dateGroup.all(), function(d) { return d.value.y + d.value.bubble*2; }) ];


var bubbleChart  = dc.bubbleChart("#bubble-chart"); 
//debugger;
bubbleChart
    .dimension(dateDim)
    .group(dateGroup)
 //             .x(d3.time.scale()
 //                   .domain([minDate, maxDate])
  //                  .nice(d3.time.day)
                    //.range(xRange))
  //                  )
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain(xRange))
    .y(d3.scale.linear().domain(yRange))

    .width(400)
    .height(400)
    .yAxisPadding(50)
    .xAxisPadding(50)
    .xAxisLabel('X')
    .yAxisLabel('Y')
    .label(function (p) {
        return p.value.label;
    })
    .renderLabel(true)
    .title(function (p) {

        return [
               "x: " + p.value.x,
               "y: " + p.value.y,
               "Bubble: " + p.value.bubble,
               ]
               .join("\n");
    })
    .renderTitle(true)
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true) // (optional) render horizontal grid lines, :default=false
    .renderVerticalGridLines(true)
    .maxBubbleRelativeSize(0.3)
    .keyAccessor(function (p) {

        return p.value.x;
    })
    .valueAccessor(function (p) {
        return p.value.y;
    })
    .radiusValueAccessor(function (p) {
        return p.value.bubble;
    });
dc.renderAll();
```

I have looked through same similar discussions here, but did not find an answer.

In my fiddle, I have lines 51 through 55 commented out, which is where my attempt at the time axis is. The line right below has `.x` as `d3.linear`, and works fine.

How do I do this properly to have my time range be my `.x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can sure be frustrating when nothing comes up in a dc.js chart, but here I think you just need to use a date when you mean a date.

I commented out the `keyAccessor` so that the chart uses the default, the `key` which is of `Date` type, and the chart draws okay.

http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/fwebkwqo/4/

(`x` is of of course not of `Date` type.)